# Sidemenu and tableview customization

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a project and with the hopes of developing my skills and providing open source package in iOS. I came across a unique interface that really got my attention which comes from a great app and there are two main things I would want to work on.

1. Pull to add and release to add. 
   This feature I know was built with a table view but how it was implemented remains unknown to me
   [image: image 1]
2. Side navigation which contains time selection. The time overlays the tableview in this part
   [image: image 2]

I would be glad if anyone could gimmie tips on how to go about this things or open source libraries that one can reference.

The application is **Sorted** you can check it out on the App Store

Answer (score 0):

Look up on the following topics,

1. UIPanGestureRecognizer (this is to recognize the pull down)
2. CGAffineTransform (to rotate the text field)
3. Movement/Transformation of the elements could be done by changing the constraint values and calling UIView's layoutIfNeeded inside an UIView animation block
4. You can make the keyboard appear by making the text field first responder

If you are interested in building rest of the features 'Sorted' has. They you may check https://cocoapods.org/pods/FoldingCell for some inspiration :)